# Why Link register in my ARM controller points to return address + 1

Tags: arm, microcontroller, cortex-m

I have a dummy code:

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        LED_Initialize();
        LED_On(0);
        delay();
        LED_Off(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Assembly for dummy code looks like:

```
0x08000416 F7FFFFB3  BL.W          LED_On (0x08000380)  
    22:                 delay();                        
0x0800041A F7FFFFF3  BL.W          delay (0x08000404)   
    23:                 LED_Off(0);                     
**0x0800041E** 2000      MOVS          r0,#0x00
```

The next instruction address is 0x0800041E but link register R14 always holds address + 1 in this case 0x0800041F.Do not really understand why ? I know it has to do something with Thumb instruction but can someone explain the entire concept and reason for it ?
I am using STM32F446REXX microcontroller.

Comment: You should not need to init the led every time through the loop, just once before you start the loop. (and a delay after on and a delay after off if you want to see it blink, otherwise it just appears to stay on).

Answer (score 4):

That is a cortex-m4 so you get the document for the cortex-m4 and it says it is based on the armv7-m architecture so you get the architectural reference manual for the cortex-m4 and

> The following instructions cause EPSR.T to be set to bit[0] of the
>   value loaded to the PC: 
>   — A BLX or BX . 
>   — An LDR to the PC. 
>   — A POP or LDM that includes the PC.

and so read about that:

> The EPSR.T bit supports the ARM architecture interworking model,
>   however, as ARMv7-M only supports execution of Thumb instructions, it
>   must always be maintained with the value 1. Updates to the PC that
>   comply with the Thumb instruction interworking rules must update the
>   EPSR.T accordingly. Instruction execution with EPSR.T set to 0 causes
>   the invalid state UsageFault, INVSTATE.

To be fair it is easier to go back to the original arm arm now called the armv5 architectural reference manual where you had/have full sized and thumb and it in a slightly better way explains that when these instructions consume that value they take the lsbit and make a mode decision on it, change/stay in arm change/stay in thumb based on bit[0].  The PC DOES NOT retain that bit, it is consumed by the instruction and sent to the T bit in the PSR.

The cortex-ms being thumb only machines must remain in that mode and as stated if you try to switch to arm then you will get a fault. (Likewise if your vector table isn't built properly with the lsbit set then you won't boot).

And please think of it is as address orred with one not address plus one because if the tools are doing things correctly then if you add one you get an invalid address and crash/fault, where if you feel you have to orr the bit you won't hurt anything (unless the address is not being used in that manner then that's another bug).

The armv7-ar doc will cover the bit[0] topic as well and what instructions can switch modes, from armv4t where it started to armv7-ar quite a few more instructions are capable of switching modes. And linkers like gnu ld will add a trampoline for you if you build code right.

You should always have the processor documentation on the screen or desk when working with the processor at this level to cover questions like these.  And again to be fair the thumb only docs appear to be written as if you already know from working with full sized arms (armv4t through armv7ar).

Comment: Wasn't able to edit this in due to the edit queue, but the link for the Architectural Reference Manual (quoted in this answer) is https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/latest